# Perl: write value in thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, file, hash

I am trying to get text of two large files. To speed it up i tried threads.
Before i used threads the script worked, now it does not.

The problem is: I save everything I read in the file into a hash.
When i print out the size (or keys/values) after the read-in in the sub (which the thread executed) it shows a correct number > 0, when i print out the size of the hash anywhere else (after the threads have run) it shows me 0.

```
print ": ".keys(%c);
```

is used 2 times, and has different output each time.
(In the final programm 2 Threads are running and a method to compare the stuff is called after the threads finished)

Example code:

```
   my %c;
   my @threads = initThreads();

   @threads[0] = threads->create(\&ce);

foreach(@threads){
    $_->join();
}
print ": ".keys(%c);


sub initThreads{
    my @initThreads;

    for(my $i = 0; $i<2;$i++){
            push(@initThreads, $i);
    }
return @initThreads;
}

sub ce(){
    my $id = threads->tid();

    open my $file, "<", @arg1[1] or die $!;

    my @cXY;
    my @cDa;

    while(my $line = <$file>){

# some regex and push to arrays, works
            @c{@cXY} = @cDa;

    }

    print "Thread $id is done\n";
    close $file;

print ": ".keys(%c);
    threads->exit();
}
```

Do i have to run the things after the first 2 threads finished in another thread which waits until the first two are finished?
Or what am i doing wrong with threads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` isn't shared across your threads.

```
use threads;
use threads::shared

my %c :shared;
```

See [threads::shared](https://metacpan.org/module/threads%3a%3ashared).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sadly it is not faster than read in the files one after another, it is even much slower...

Comment: Is it faster in the non-shared threaded version (even if it is incorrect)?  Sharing data does have costs.  The hash is locked each time it's accessed; you're effectively blocking the other threads when that happens.
You might want to try the approach in the other answer which suggests returning the data from the thread.  That will completely isolate the threads.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, threads don't share memory. Each thread operates on a different *copy* of `%c`, so the changes aren't reflected to the parent thread. While sharing a variable across threads is possible, this is not generally advisable.

Make use of the possibility to *return* data from a thread. E.g

```
my %c = map %{ $_->join }, @threads; # flatten all returned hashes

sub ce {
  my %hash; 
  ...;
  return \%hash;
}
```

---

Some other suggestions:

- `use strict; use warnings;` if you aren't already.
- use better variable names.
- you only seem to be spawning one thread (in `$threads[0]`).
- `my @array; for (my $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){ push(@array, $i) }` is equivalent to `my @array = 0 .. 1`.
- `@arg1` is not declared in the current scope.
- manually `exit`ing a thread is not neccessary in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i already do almost everything you wrote, i just did not wanted to copy the whole script. What i did not knew was that exiting is not neccessary here.